# rails paperclip image upload Encoding::UndefinedConversionError ("\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8):

Tags: ruby, paperclip

I have used paperclip for image storage and when I try to upload and save the image, image it getting saved but I am getting `Encoding::UndefinedConversionError` while redirecting to other page.

I tried to remove the paperclip code and do the same with normal file upload mechanism, but result is the same.

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"janP4YndP+9xORuxP5BkEuRFpVZi7GvLcs3u+6RsSfs=", "user"=>{"profile_picture"=>#ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x3622916a @original_filename="36.jpg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[profile_picture]\"; filename=\"36.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/home/ROOT/RackMultipart.13883.61589>, @content_type="image/jpeg">}}


Command :: file -b --mime 
 '/home/ROOT/36130617-13883-1gqm197-61590130617-13883-1uub191-61593'
(1.0ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `avatar_file_name` = '36.jpg', `avatar_file_size` = 107409, `avatar_updated_at` = '2013-06-17 13:44:04', `updated_at` = '2013-06-17 13:44:04' WHERE `users`.`id` = 10
 [paperclip] deleting /home/ROOT/public/system/users/avatars/000/000/010/original/123.jpg
 [paperclip] deleting /home/ROOT/public/system/users/avatars/000/000/010/medium/123.jpg
 [paperclip] deleting /home/ROOT/public/system/users/avatars/000/000/010/thumb/123.jpg
Redirected to url


Encoding::UndefinedConversionError - "\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8:
  org/jruby/RubyString.java:7580:in `encode'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:123:in `escape'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:69:in `escape'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:171:in `encode_json'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:214:in `encode_json'
  org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2361:in `map'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:214:in `encode_json'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:48:in `encode'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:77:in `check_for_circular_references'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:46:in `encode'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:246:in `encode_json'
  org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1257:in `each'
  org/jruby/RubyEnumerable.java:718:in `map'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:246:in `encode_json'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:48:in `
```

I checked with the paperclip gem and it uses binmode for opening  the file.

Comment: Maybe the string you are feeding it isn't binary? Maybe `str.force_encoding('BINARY')` will do the trick.

Comment: Any success? I've got exactly the same issue.

Comment: I have added a work-around to achieve that 
I have created the file manually by opening it in write mode and then givan the path for that to paperclip and then deleted that temp file after paperclip completes its activity

Comment: It would be great if you post your solution as answer here.

Answer (score 0):

> Removed support for the encode_json hook used for encoding custom
>   objects into JSON. This feature has been extracted into the
>   activesupport-json_encoder gem.

Add activesupport-json_encoder gem to Gemfile fix this issue.